# MFC: FrameRgn is not framing the entire region

Tags: winapi, mfc

I created a dialog based application From dialog properties, **i removed Title bar and Set border is none**.Then ProgmaticallyI modified the dialog size using MOveWindow() and i change the dialog shape to a polygon region and applied frame region. its working fine.

But when I created a dialog based application **Progmatically, i removed Title bar and Dialog frame** as below:

```
ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION,0);
ModifyStyle(WS_DLGFRAME,0)
```

- Then ProgmaticallyI modified the dialog size using MOveWindow() and i change the dialog shape to a polygonregion and applied frame region. The frame is not appearing around the dialog. its there only in left and top.

  BOOL CDialogShapeDlg::OnInitDialog()
  {
      CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  ```
  ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION,0);
  ModifyStyle(WS_DLGFRAME,0);

  CRect rect;
  GetClientRect(&rect);
  MoveWindow(rect.left,rect.top,400,500);

  GetClientRect(&rect);
  CPoint vertex[4];
  vertex[0] = CPoint(rect.left,rect.top);
  vertex[1] = CPoint(rect.right,rect.top);
  vertex[2] = CPoint(rect.right,rect.bottom);
  vertex[3] = CPoint(rect.left,rect.bottom);


  rgn.CreatePolygonRgn(vertex,4,ALTERNATE);
  HGDIOBJ hRgn = rgn.Detach();
  ::SetWindowRgn(GetSafeHwnd(), (HRGN)hRgn, TRUE);
  rgn.CreatePolygonRgn(vertex,4,ALTERNATE);
  return TRUE;
  ```

  }

  void CDialogShapeDlg::OnPaint()
      {
          CPaintDC dc(this); 
          CBrush *pBrush = new CBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
          dc.FrameRgn(&rgn,pBrush,1,1);
      }

Please help on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using regions is an advanced feature and from your code and questions, you are a beginner.  You should read more about programming Windows.  Then you would know that you probably be using GetWindowRect() and not GetClientRect().  GetClientRect() returns the size of the client area of the window in the coordinates of the client space of the window.

Comment: Actually i wanted to draw the frame around the client area. So from the dialog i removed the border and caption. So now the remaining is the client area. Then i am trying to draw a frame around it. So i used GetClientArea. Even if i use GetWindowRect as per your suggestion, still i have the same issue.

Comment: If you just want to draw the frame, then don't remove the style.  That is not going to work.  Instead, handle the WM_NCPAINT message.

Comment: My requirement is i want to draw a frame around the dialog after removing the dialog title bar/border/frame. But it looks weird for me like, if i remove the window style from the dialog properties, then the same code is working  working fine, but if i try to remove by code, then the issue.

Comment: The requirement is wrong and ignores how Windows works.